# Changing the server path

Tags: server, paths

We have a WordPress multisite set up and working fine, but now the owner wants to change the server path to a different name. Will WordPress be able to automatically continue working with the new server pathname, or is there something we need to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress doesn't rely on server path, it relies on the URI. When the WordPress code is loaded, it will define the proper paths itself dynamically by using PHP constants like `__FILE__`, such as `ABSPATH` which is the absolute path to the WordPress's installation.

So, as long as your domain remains the same, you should not experience any problem.